# How to create a proper CheckButton in Tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

Im trying to create a `CheckButton` in `tkinter` based on the items I have in my equipment `list`. The `CheckButton` has been created but not all the items that are in `equipment` are visible in the app. Is it because my items are to large?

**This is my code:**

```
from tkinter import *

owner = ['Spain', 'United Kingdom', 'Malaysia']
vehicleid = ['C161', 'C162']
equipment = ['X-tron senistra beamer mode version 5.4433', 
            'Loadcell compact designer 2000 version 32.44',
            'Streamcell highspeed collision extra large version 8.5']

window = Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script") # Create window
window.geometry('550x300') # Geo of the window

##These are the option menus
dd_owner = StringVar(window)
dd_owner.set(owner[0]) # the first value
w = OptionMenu(window, dd_owner, *owner)
w.grid(row=1, column=1)

dd_id = StringVar(window)
dd_id.set(vehicleid[0])
w0 = OptionMenu(window, dd_id, *vehicleid)
w0.grid(row=0, column=1)

#This is the CheckButton
dd_equipment = Checkbutton
for x in equipment:
    dd_equipment = Checkbutton(window, text=x, variable=x)
    dd_equipment.grid(row=2, column=1)

##The run button 
run_list_button =Button(window, text="Send data of ID's to database!")
run_list_button.grid(column=0, row=3)

##These are the titles
l1 = Label(window, text='Select Owner', width=15)
l1.grid(row=1, column=0)

l0 = Label(window, text='Select vehicle id:', width = 30)
l0.grid(row=0, column=0)

l0 = Label(window, text='Select equipment:', width = 30)
l0.grid(row=2, column=0)

mainloop()
```

**This is how the tkinter app looks like:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens, because in:

```
for x in equipment:
    dd_equipment = Checkbutton(window, text=x, variable=x)
    dd_equipment.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

you are packing every Checkbutton to the same position. Hence, with every iteration, the previous Checkbutton is replaced and only the one for your last item (`'Streamcell highspeed collision extra large version 8.5'`) shows.

To correct this, you could, for example, do this instead:

```
for i,x in enumerate(equipment):
    dd_equipment = Checkbutton(window, text=x, variable=x)
    dd_equipment.grid(row=2+i, column=1, sticky=W)
```

Comment: That is already one step better. But they don't look that well alligned if you run it. Is their an option to make it even more neater?

Comment: Try sticky="w" option

Answer (score 1):

Your code never changes the row or the column of the placement. Hence they all overlap. Here are 2 possible solutions

```
val=1
for x in equipment:
    dd_equipment = Checkbutton(window, text=x, variable=x)
    dd_equipment.grid(row=val, column=1)
    val+=1
```

```
for val,x in enumerate(equipment):
    dd_equipment = Checkbutton(window, text=x, variable=x)
    dd_equipment.grid(row=val, column=1)
```

Comment: Check my reaction on the answer below. It looks already better, but they are not aligned. Can I make it look neater?

Comment: Ah yes! that worked. Just saw it. Mind to enter the https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232816/discussion ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are placing/packing all thecheckbuttons to the same position, so to avoid this, instead of :

```
dd_equipment.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

you can do:

```
dd_equipment.grid(row=i+2, column=1, sticky=W)
```